# Projection onto a subspace in plain english

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Is the projection of a vector, v onto a subspace X just the vector x belonging to X that is orthogonal to v and closer to v than every other vector in X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> closer to $v$ than every other vector in $X$?

Yes, that is correct -- and this property alone is enough to define the projection.

> just the vector x belonging to X that is orthogonal to v and

No, rather the vector $x-v$ is orthogonal to every vector in the subspace $X$.

#### Sketch of Proof

Let $u\in X$. By assumption $\|x+tu - v \|^2\ge \|x-v\|^2$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Converting the norm to dot product and simplifying, you will find that $\langle x-v, u\rangle =0$. The key point is that if a quadratic polynomial in $t$ attains its minimum at $t=0$, then the coefficient of $t$ is $0$.

Comment: Ooh. Hmm okay that makes sense. Is there any way to prove that x - v is orthogonal to every vector in the subspace?

Comment: what does the angle bracket mean? in the <x-v, u> expression?

Comment: [Dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product), also known as $(x-v)\cdot u$.